# Using dynamic sink destination in Akka Streams

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm rather new to Akka and am trying to learn the basics. My use case is to continually read messages from a JMS queue and output each message to a new file. I have the basic setup working with:

```
Source<String, NotUsed> jmsSource =
  JmsSource
    .textSource(JmsSourceSettings
    .create(connectionFactory)
    .withQueue("myQueue")
    .withBufferSize(10));

Sink<ByteString, CompletionStage<IOResult>> fileSink =
  FileIO.toFile(new File("random.txt"));

final Flow<String, ByteString, NotUsed> flow = Flow.fromFunction((String n) -> ByteString.fromString(n));

final RunnableGraph<NotUsed> runnable = jmsSource.via(flow).to(fileSink);

runnable.run(materializer);
```

However, I want the file name to be dynamic (and not hard-coded to "random.txt"): it should be changed depending on the content of each message on the queue. I could, of course, pick up the file name in the flow, but how do I set that name in `fileSink`? How do I best set this up?

Comment: Every time I come back to Akka Streams I always seem to end up wanting this too. I solved it once it the past but I can't remember how. I think I took some inspiration from Akka Http.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out a solution here?

Comment: Sadly no. I was extremely surprised there was no easy way of doing this as it seems to be such a basic feature. I was almost certain there was something I had missed...but the responses to this question showed I probably had to write some custom handling for this, and that pretty much told me this isn't the right implementation for this type of use-case (hope I'm wrong though).

Answer (score 3):

I created a simple Sink based on `akka.stream.impl.LazySink`. I have only tested it with a single element in the successful case so feel free to comment on here or the [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/steinybot/cd9aeac534a45aead54c4cea089e0e40).

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.{Attributes, Inlet, SinkShape}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.stage._

class OneToOneOnDemandSink[T, +M](sink: T => Sink[T, M]) extends GraphStage[SinkShape[T]] {

  val in: Inlet[T] = Inlet("OneToOneOnDemandSink.in")
  override val shape = SinkShape(in)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes) = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {

    override def preStart(): Unit = pull(in)

    val awaitingElementHandler = new InHandler {
      override def onPush(): Unit = {
        val element = grab(in)
        val innerSource = createInnerSource(element)
        val innerSink = sink(element)
        Source.fromGraph(innerSource.source).runWith(innerSink)(subFusingMaterializer)
      }

      override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = completeStage()

      override def onUpstreamFailure(ex: Throwable): Unit = failStage(ex)
    }
    setHandler(in, awaitingElementHandler)

    def createInnerSource(element: T): SubSourceOutlet[T] = {
      val innerSource = new SubSourceOutlet[T]("OneToOneOnDemandSink.innerSource")

      innerSource.setHandler(new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          innerSource.push(element)
          innerSource.complete()
          if (isClosed(in)) {
            completeStage()
          } else {
            pull(in)
            setHandler(in, awaitingElementHandler)
          }
        }

        override def onDownstreamFinish(): Unit = {
          innerSource.complete()
          if (isClosed(in)) {
            completeStage()
          }
        }
      })

      setHandler(in, new InHandler {
        override def onPush(): Unit = {
          val illegalStateException = new IllegalStateException("Got a push that we weren't expecting")
          innerSource.fail(illegalStateException)
          failStage(illegalStateException)
        }

        override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
          // We don't stop until the inner stream stops.
          setKeepGoing(true)
        }

        override def onUpstreamFailure(ex: Throwable): Unit = {
          innerSource.fail(ex)
          failStage(ex)
        }
      })

      innerSource
    }
  }
}

object OneToOneOnDemandSink {

  def apply[T, M](sink: T => Sink[T, M]): Sink[T, NotUsed] = Sink.fromGraph(new OneToOneOnDemandSink(sink))
}
```

This will create a new Sink for each element so it avoids a whole lot of the complexity that `LazySink` has and there is also no sensible materialized value to return.

Answer (score 1):

Below are three equivalent approaches:

- one more terse, using `map` and an inner graph,
- one more terse, using `flatMapConcat` and an inner graph,
- one more verbose, using the `GraphDSL`.

In all cases, the output is:

```
$ tail -n +1 -- *.txt
==> 1.txt <==
1

==> 2.txt <==
2

==> 3.txt <==
3

==> 4.txt <==
4

==> 5.txt <==
5
```

---

1. Using `map`:

   ```
   import java.nio.file.Paths

   import akka.actor.ActorSystem
   import akka.stream._
   import akka.stream.scaladsl.{FileIO, Sink, Source}
   import akka.util.ByteString

   import scala.concurrent.Future

   object Example extends App {
     override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       implicit val system = ActorSystem("Example")
       implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

       val result: Future[Seq[Future[IOResult]]] = Source(1 to 5)
         .map(
           elem => Source.single(ByteString(s"$elem\n"))
               .runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(s"$elem.txt")))
         )
         .runWith(Sink.seq)

       implicit val ec = system.dispatcher
       result.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
     }
   }
   ```

   **Explanation**:
   We `map` the `Int` element to a function which creates an inner graph, `Source.single(ByteString(...)).runWith(FileIO.toPath(...)`, which serializes and writes to a dynamic path, and allows us to accumulate the resulting `Future[IOResult]` via `Sink.seq`.

   **Documentation**:

   > `map`
   >   Transform each element in the stream by calling a mapping function with it and passing the returned value downstream.
   >
   > **emits** when the mapping function returns an element
   >
   > **backpressures** when downstream backpressures
   >
   > **completes** when upstream completes

   **See also**:

   - https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stages-overview.html#map

---

2. Using [`flatMapConcat`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stages-overview.html#flatmapconcat):

   ```
   import java.nio.file.Paths

   import akka.actor.ActorSystem
   import akka.stream._
   import akka.stream.scaladsl.{FileIO, Sink, Source}
   import akka.util.ByteString

   import scala.concurrent.Future

   object Example extends App {
     override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       implicit val system = ActorSystem("Example")
       implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

       val result: Future[Seq[Future[IOResult]]] = Source(1 to 5)
         .flatMapConcat(
           elem => Source.single(
             Source.single(ByteString(s"$elem\n"))
               .runWith(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(s"$elem.txt")))
           )
         )
         .runWith(Sink.seq)

       implicit val ec = system.dispatcher
       result.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
     }
   }
   ```

   **Explanation**:
   `flatMapConcat` requires a `Source`. We therefore create one which emits the `mat` of the inner graph, `Source.single(ByteString(...)).runWith(FileIO.toPath(...)`, which allows us to accumulate the resulting `Future[IOResult]` via `Sink.seq`. Actual serialization and dispatch is done by the inner graph.

   **Documentation**:

   > `flatMapConcat`
   >   Transform each input element into a `Source` whose elements are then flattened into the output stream through concatenation. This means each source is fully consumed before consumption of the next source starts.
   >
   > **emits** when the current consumed substream has an element available
   >
   > **backpressures** when downstream backpressures
   >
   > **completes** when upstream completes and all consumed substreams complete

   **See also**:

   - https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stages-overview.html#flatmapconcat
   - https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-substream.html#flatmapconcat

---

3. Custom `Sink` using the `GraphDSL`:

   ```
   import java.nio.file.Path

   import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Broadcast, FileIO, Flow, GraphDSL, Sink, Source, ZipWith}
   import akka.stream.{IOResult, Materializer, SinkShape}
   import akka.util.ByteString

   import scala.concurrent.Future

   object FileSinks {
     def dispatch[T](
                      dispatcher: T => Path,
                      serializer: T => ByteString
                    )(
                      implicit materializer: Materializer
                    ): Sink[T, Future[Seq[Future[IOResult]]]] =
       Sink.fromGraph(
         GraphDSL.create(
           Sink.seq[Future[IOResult]]
         ) {
           implicit builder =>
             sink =>
               // prepare this sink's graph elements:
               val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[T](2))
               val serialize = builder.add(Flow[T].map(serializer))
               val dispatch = builder.add(Flow[T].map(dispatcher))
               val zipAndWrite = builder.add(ZipWith[ByteString, Path, Future[IOResult]](
                 (bytes, path) => Source.single(bytes).runWith(FileIO.toPath(path)))
               )

               // connect the graph:
               import GraphDSL.Implicits._
               broadcast.out(0) ~> serialize ~> zipAndWrite.in0
               broadcast.out(1) ~> dispatch ~> zipAndWrite.in1
               zipAndWrite.out ~> sink

               // expose ports:
               SinkShape(broadcast.in)
         }
       )
   }
   ----
   import java.nio.file.Paths

   import FileSinks
   import akka.actor.ActorSystem
   import akka.stream._
   import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
   import akka.util.ByteString

   import scala.concurrent.Future

   object Example extends App {
     override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       implicit val system = ActorSystem("Example")
       implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

       val result: Future[Seq[Future[IOResult]]] = Source(1 to 5)
         .runWith(FileSinks.dispatch[Int](
           elem => Paths.get(s"$elem.txt"),
           elem => ByteString(s"$elem\n"))
         )

       implicit val ec = system.dispatcher
       result.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
     }
   }
   ```

   - `dispatcher` is a function to convert your input object to a path, this is where you can dynamically decide on the path.
   - `serializer` is a function to serialise your input object.
   - the rest uses the `GraphDSL`, see also: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html#constructing-graphs

---

**Disclaimer**: I am myself still in the process of learning Akka Stream.